# SQL Server Reporting Services - localize reports?

Tags: localization, internationalization, globalization, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have some SSRS 2008 reports that need to be localized. That is:

1. Report titles, column headers, etc. **all** need to be in the user's locale. (Note that in my situation, the User!Language expression may or may not be useful, but that's not the major problem.)
2. The localized strings must be retrievable from a table within the same DB as the actual report data. Separate localized RDLs won't work for us. Localization will be managed by non-developers, so we've provided a UI for them to change localized strings themselves.
3. We'd **very** much prefer not to retrieve strings through a custom assembly, if we can help it. We've had trouble in the past deploying custom assemblies, and of course it introduces some debugging complexity as well.

All ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need a table on the db with everyone's country preference against their user ID. Then based on the user ID you can set the formatting accordingly.

Pretty bad practice though. Why can't you use User!Language?